# Convert epub to kepub from command-line

Tags: epub, kobo, kobo-glo

I’m trying to convert `epub`s to the `kepub` format, but would like to automate the process by doing it via CLI.

So far, I had no luck in finding a tool that would allow it. Closest I found was a [KePub Output plugin](https://github.com/jgoguen/calibre-kobo-driver) for Calibre, but [it fails to work on the command-line, and won’t be fixed for a long while](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre-kobo-driver/+bug/1481534).

Is there a tool I’m missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to look for this again today, and found some GitHub repositories and scripts. I tested the ones that looked more promising (recently updated, easy setup), and it seems like both did the job well.

- [`kepubify`](https://github.com/geek1011/kepubify). Written in [Go](https://golang.org/), [the author](https://github.com/geek1011) is reasonably active and seems to be generally interested in the subject of kepubs, judging from the repos.
- [`kepuber`](https://github.com/matthistuff/kepuber), written in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/).

Comment: Hi. I'm the author of kepubify. A quick note: as of November 2017, there are conversion problems on Windows, which I am working on fixing. The Linux and macOS versions work fine.

Comment: I have fixed the issue on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact answer to your question, but you can select multiple files on your calibre library, right click, select `convert` > `group convert`, and on the following window select `kepub` as the output format (provided that you have installed the corresponding plugin).
If your concern was to convert multiple files at once, this could be a solution.

Another thing that you might want to try, is to go to the program settings, go in the `Add books` section, and check the second tab `Automatic adding`: here you can specify a folder where Calibre will look for books to be automatically imported in your library, and optionally convert them to a format of your liking; again, this could be a solution to your issue.

If you wanted to include the conversion process in a script, however, these tricks won't be useful; I'm not very knowledgeable of Calibre CLI interface, so I can't help you further.

**Please Note** that I'm using Calibre with the italian interface, so the previous menu entries can be a little different from what I've written, they are just what I've translated on-the-fly.

Comment: Thank you, but I’m really looking to do it via CLI.

Comment: I'm sorry then, I can't help you. You could try carefully reading the official Calibre manual and documentation, and visit the forums at Mobileread, they have a section dedicated to Calibre visited by the developers too.

Comment: That wouldn’t help. My time would be better spent by reading up on the differences between a kepub and an epub (since they’re pretty similar) and building a tool myself for the conversion, than going on a rabbit hunt. I’m trying to find if there is a way to do it already precisely to avoid that.